# React State not getting updated onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-forms

I am new in ReactJS and I am working on a simple app to display 2 screens (single app, no routes) where the user puts data in, then a screen displays all the data and you can click a dummy submit button that says "Success".
I am using context and 2 pieces of state. One to track where I am and another to update the user info.

The first page works well but when I click continue and I expect my step to become 2 and to render the next screen, nothing happens and I get an blank screen. My step never gets updated and in the console I see an error "Uncaught Exception: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

The code I have is the following:
Context:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const Context = React.createContext()

function ContextProvider ({children}) {
  
  const [userData, setUserData]  = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    occupation: "",
    city: "",
    bio: ""
  })
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1)
  
  const {firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio} = userData
  const values = {firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio}

  // Proceed to next step
  function nextStep () { 
    setStep(prevState => prevState.step + 1)
  }

  // Go back to prev step
  function prevStep () {
    setStep(prevState => prevState.step - 1)
  }

  // Handle fields change
  function handleChange (e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{userData, step, values, nextStep, prevStep, handleChange}}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}


export {ContextProvider, Context}
```

App:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import UserForm from "./components/UserForm"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

UserForm:

```js
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";
import {Context} from "../UserFormContext"

import FormUserDetails from './FormUserDetails';
import FormPersonalDetails from './FormPersonalDetails';
import Confirm from './Confirm';
import Success from './Success';

function UserForm () {
    const {userData, step, values, handleChange, nextStep, prevStep} = useContext(Context)

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
          return (
            console.log(step),
            console.log(userData),
            <FormUserDetails
              nextStep={nextStep}
              handleChange={handleChange}
              values={values}
            />
          )
        case 2:
          return (
            console.log(step),
            <FormPersonalDetails
              nextStep={nextStep}
              prevStep={prevStep}
              handleChange={handleChange}
              values={values}
            />
          )
        case 3:
          return (
            <Confirm
              nextStep={nextStep}
              prevStep={prevStep}
              values={values}
            />
          )
        case 4:
          return <Success />
        default:
          (console.log('This is a multi-step form built with React.'))
    }
}

export default UserForm
```

FormUserDetails:

```js
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";
import {Context} from "../UserFormContext"

import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'


export function FormUserDetails () {

  const {userData, step, values, handleChange, nextStep} = useContext(Context)
  
  function Continue (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    nextStep()
  }

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <>
        <Dialog
          open
          fullWidth
          maxWidth='sm'
        >
          <AppBar title="Enter User Details" />
          <TextField
            placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
            label="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleChange(e, 'name')}}
            defaultValue={userData.firstName}
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"
            label="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleChange(e, 'name')}}
            defaultValue={userData.lastName}
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            placeholder="Enter Your Email"
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleChange(e, 'name')}}
            defaultValue={userData.email}
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
          <br />
          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={(e) => Continue(e)}
          >Continue</Button>
        </Dialog>
      </>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default FormUserDetails
```

When I click the continue button in FormUserDetails the step should change to 2 and the UserForm should render case 2 which is the next form. Or at least it should happen but it doesn't :)

Any helping hand?

Comment: Are you using the `ContextProvider` somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, in index.js. I wrap the App with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error with your step functions. You should remove the `.step` from them

they should be

```
  // Proceed to next step
  function nextStep () { 
    setStep(prevState => prevState + 1)
  }

  // Go back to prev step
  function prevStep () {
    setStep(prevState => prevState - 1)
  }
```

Comment: oh man, obvious mistake. I used to have step as part of my userData state and I decoupled it later on but forgot to change the methods to set it. Thanks a lot!